# Linux Command to get Disk throughput

Tags: linux

I want to know Disk i/o waits, Disk Throughput metrics of my linux machine. 
Are there any Linux commands to get disk throughput? Please help me.

Comment: hi, try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of tools available for different IO metrics (bytes written, system processes r/w statistics etc.).

You have to read through their documentation and see what fits your needs. To get you started:

- iotop - http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/
- dstat - https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat (alternative to iostat)
- iodump - https://github.com/true/aspersa-mirror/blob/master/iodump

Answer (score -1):

There are a whole range to choose from , ranging from dd if you want to benchmark the disk , right through (pun) to a suite of utilities like 'iostat' a would suggest a quick google to see which best meets your requirements